# Error in plsql statement while executing in DB2 through putty

Tags: plsql, db2

I have created following DB2 plsql script and trying to run the .sql file through putty. But im getting following error;

```
BEGIN
DECLARE abc  VARCHAR2(15)
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "abc  
VARCHAR2(15)".  Expected tokens may include:  "<psm_semicolon>".  LINE 
NUMBER=2.  SQLSTATE=42601

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "IN" was found following "FOR abc  ".  
Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

following is the sample plsql statement i have written.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE abc VARCHAR2(15);
  FOR abc IN (SELECT empid  FROM employee where mark=2 order by 1) LOOP
    Insert into salary
      (id,
       name,mark)
      SELECT id,
             name,
             3
        FROM salary A
       WHERE id=abc.empid and mark=2; 
         
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
  END;
/
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact command line that you give in the ssh session , to run this script.   You need to specify the block delimiter correctly, according to how you are running the script.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `DECLARE` keyword before `BEGIN` or put `BEGIN` after `DECLARE` if that's what you wanted to do.
The error occurs because of lack of `BEGIN` keyword after declaring section.
Your code could look like:

```
DECLARE 
  abc VARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
  FOR abc IN (SELECT empid  FROM employee where mark=2 order by 1) 
  LOOP
    Insert into salary
      (
       id,
       name,
       mark
      )
      SELECT id,
             name,
             3
      FROM salary A
      WHERE id=abc.empid 
            and mark=2; 
         
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
  END;
```